# Are PHP suspended generator functions costing resources?

Tags: php, generator

I wrote a cache holder like this:

```
<?php                                                                            

function expensive() {                                                           
  sleep(3);                                                                      
  yield "expensive result";                                                      
}                                                                                


$container = [];                                                                 
function cache_holder($key, $data) {                                             
  global $container;
  if (!isset($container[$key])) {                                                
    $container[$key] = $data->current();
  }                                                                              
  return $container[$key];
}

// run

$start = microtime(true);                                                        

$first_fetch = cache_holder('foo', expensive());
echo $first_fetch, "\n";                       
$end_first = microtime(true);
printf("elapsed time: %.2f ms \n", ($end_first - $start) * 1000);

$second_fetch = cache_holder('foo', expensive());
echo $second_fetch, "\n";                               
$end_second = microtime(true);
printf("elapsed time: %.2f ms \n", ($end_second - $end_first) * 1000);
```

According to [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators#basic_behavior), `expensive()` is suspended and resumed when `->current()` called:

> When a generator function is called the execution is suspended immediately after parameter binding and a Generator object is returned.

My questions are: are those suspended functions costing resources? any drawback with the approach above?

Comment: They should be occupying memory for all the variables they hold, but virtually no other overhead beyond that. I do not know the details of how they're implemented, but it seems like a common sense case.